# How can i show Swipe-out show right default button in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

developing sample application. How can i show the swipe-out based in right side default button using react-native.
 Actually i am getting like this below image:
[image]

But i want getting like this when list is Open:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add touch on listcell. i have a simple demo [here](https://github.com/yangguang1029/MyReactNative/blob/master/SwipeoutList.js)

Comment: But I want show at least one  showed when its list view is opend